# How to achieve OrdinalColumn property in mdx for kylin by Kylegence

Tags: kylin

I have some time details columns like Month Name it shows in values in alphabetical order Like April, August etc But i want is January, February based on Calender Month Number

if i try to order this explicitly by mdx on member value that
sequence of moving average get's deviated
Please help me with this if anyone having solution for that